# How can i upload an mp3 audio file to php from Android using volley?

Tags: java, php, android, mp3, encode

I want to upload an mp3 file located in a local folder in android, file plays fine in android.
When I upload it using **base64 encoding**, the file size is too small on the server and it won't play, so I guess is not a correct **mp3** file.

I currently use this for images and it works fine:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, byteArrayOutputStream);
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And this is for the audio upload:

```
private void UploadAudio() {

           try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));
            jsonObject.put("name", "myaudiorecording.mp3");
            jsonObject.put("audio", uri);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONObject Here", e.toString());
        }


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://ip/audioUpload.php", jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                        int responseCode = jsonObject.optInt("success");

                        Log.e("upload", "Success");

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                Log.e("upload", volleyError.toString());

            }

        });
}
```

Comment: In my opinion you should upload mp3 file in mutlipart.

Comment: So it can’t be done with volley?

Comment: Http Multipart requests are used to send heavy data data or files like audio and video to the server.You can use volley and you should upload mp3 in Multipart data using volley.

Comment: Actually it's not heavy data, files are small low quality mp3 recordings about 50 - 100kb, that's why I was trying to use Base64 encoding

Comment: Whenever you send base64 of audio to server :-Compare with base64 in android with base64 string of server which you passed with api.Its both same?